# File based storage Vs Database Storage

Tags: database, storage

our company at present stores a lot of automatically generated files on disk, this presnetly is well over 200,000 files, there PDF's and are around 100k - 1M in size.

ive been asked to provide some evidence for the pro's and Cons of storing this data in files vs storing it as database records..

i would like to see us where possible store this data in a MS SQL or MySQL db etc rather than having 200,000 files knocking around a pile of local directories.

what id like from you guys is some good solid reasons for using either system so i can weigh up the difference and put my case forward.

Comment: Your use case will dictate what kind of solution is appropriate: Can you tell us more about how you're using these documents, what kind of controls you need (versioning?), etc…

Comment: The comments added to @Craig's answer really should be added to the question; they offer a much fuller explanation of what OP is trying to accomplish.  I don't yet have the rep, or I'd move it up there myself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly cannot see any advantage gained by storing these documents in a database. Since the docs don't get altered, neither version control systems nor document management systems will add any value.

The best you can do really is to get them stored on a separate server with a file system that excels at fast retrieval (possibly XFS, read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReiserFS)). What might help is a good organisation of the folder structure itself, e.g. in the case of insurance claims a superstructure by year and month, or in the case of insurance contacts a superstructure ordered by the first few digits/characters of the policy number.

Answer (score 1):

There is some value is storing the files in a document oriented database. But, it depends entirely on how you are using the files, how often they are accessed, how fast they need to be accessed. There are also document management systems that may be a good fit. You need to detail out your use case first.

Comment: the files are mainly for record keeping within our back end system and client data. we have a set of bespoke back end systems that allow our users to create documents, attache scans, and add new document "packs" (can be 4 ,5, 6 docs per pack).

a client would submit an insurance case to us, this would get processed on our system all of the clients details are stored in a database, however documentation would get created as PDF files and saved into a folder on our fileserver that has a reference that matches there case, (this location is also stored in a database field), the only time someone

Comment: would need to see these docs would be from the clients point of view to see there policy, reprint lost docs etc, the same for our workers internally. there is very rarely a need to ammend the original documents, instead an adjustment transaction would be added to the clients policy with new documents generated on it.

so its more of a read only archive of client policies, client data etc, that is accessible to them and our workers when needed, the files are static and only

Comment: ever get added too, due to regulations and other insurance based safe guards we are not allowed to delete or remove this data, it also has to be stored for a minimum of 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

Is there anything broken or cumbersome about your current storage scheme?  The transition cost of moving your files into a database will be nontrivial.  Putting the pain of switching aside, here are some things to consider:

- Data Consistency: you didn't specify what file system/platform you're
  using, but a database *might* provide better integrity checks for
  individual files.
- Off-site Recovery: most DBAs worth anything know how to use the
  replication features of their database.
- Backup: depending on the situation your database vendor may provide
  you with backup options (log assisted backup, snap shots, consistent
  hot backups) your OS may not provide.
- Logging/Auditing: security features of most modern databases should
  provide you with a record of who has accessed each file.
- Data Privacy: is encrypting data in your database of choice easier
  than on your OS?

Technically, there's a file system/OS based solution for each of the points I listed (eg, rsync, kernel level audting, file system encryption). If what you have is adequate for your current and projected needs, you can't beat the simplicity of a file system.  However, if your organization has strong DBA skills and a thin Sys Admin team, you might be better off with a database.  The decision might be easy if your DBA's already have established, proven procedures to meet all of your requirements.

Comment: +1 I'd also mention the performance impact of storing binary files in the database vs. file system references.  With lower-end hardware, could negatively impact I/O, memory footprint, etc. Another positive would be portability: all your data is in one place; makes recovery a simpler process.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it may not necessarily be "file system" vs. "database" as much as possibly more of a data management, access and protection comparison? Maybe around things like:

- Protect with replication and/or error detection/correction against lost
- Storage management with deduplication and/or expandability
- Client accessibility (native versus custom application/interface)
- Reporting options